# Mongoose JS: return populated data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I'm trying to build a CMS, and I may have something like this in DB:

```
// an article in Article collection
{
    "_id": ObjectId("1234"),
    "title": "JavaScript Basics",
    "category": ObjectId("0001")
}

// a category in Category collection
{
    "_id": ObjectId("0001"),
    "name": "JavaScript"
}
```

There are some reasons I have to put categories in a collection, not embedded document.
When fetch article, I want to get info like this:

```
{
    "title": "JavaScript Basics",
    "category": "JavaScript"
}
```

I tried to use Mongoose's `populate`:

```
Article.findOne({_id: "1234"})
.populate('tags', 'name -_id')
.exec()
.then(article => { /* ... */ })
```

and I got

```
{
    "title": "JavaScript Basics",
    "category": {"name": "JavaScript"}
    // compare to: "category": "JavaScript"
}
```

So I have to handle the `category`, which I think is not very elegant. Is there any solution to handle this problem?

Also, I'm thinking if it's possible to put the "find category by id" codes to mongoose's getters and setters:

```
ArticleSchema.path('category')
.set(function(categoryName) {
    // find categoryId by categoryName and set it
})
.get(function(categoryId) {
    // find category name by id and return it
});
```

It will be good if it works and I don't need face the problem mentioned before. But it seems that async codes (find category by id) is not supported here, is that possible to achieve these things in mongoose's setters and getters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are populating the populate should be present before the callback function because the we need the populated object so we put it before the .exec().

```
Article.findOne({_id: "1234"}).populate('tags', 'name').exec(function(err,article){})
```

Comment: Please add some context to your answer so people can understand better your answer